# angular templateRef passed to parent using structural directive not rendering inside parent component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

I am trying to render template in a child element of a parent componenet depending on it's type value as explained in this schema

[image]

I am passing the ng-template to parent view(my container) using myTemplateDirective

```
  --myTemplateDirective--
 this.parent.setDirective(this);

 --my-container--
 setDirective(test) {
    this.tmpl = test;
 }
```

in my container I pass it to my-componenet who has the directive as input and renders it

```
const element = this.template.renderTemplate(this.data ,this.viewContainerRef);


  renderTemplate(templateData, vcRef) {
this.renderCount++;

const viewData = {
  $implicit: {
    data: templateData,
    renderCount: this.renderCount
  }
};
const childView = vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, viewData);

// =========== WORKAROUND =============
// We have to use private API to force DOM to update
// childView['detectChanges']();
// =========== /WORKAROUND =============


this.cd.detectChanges();

return childView.rootNodes[0];
}
```

after creating the embeddedView the result I get from return childView.rootNodes[0] is :

```
<!---->
```

I have created a plunker containing all the code to better understand the problem
[plunker sample code](https://plnkr.co/edit/XTyoihEHi9ZeBr1C?p=preview)

Comment: You have to levels of template since you apply a structural directive to an ng-template, this will wrap the ng-template with another ng-template, is this wanted ?

Comment: having two ng-tempalte is not wanted, i replaced the ng-template by a div and it's working fine thank you @jo_va.

Comment: I added an answer to document the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your diagram, you seem to have two nested `ng-template`.

Angular will transform the following which uses a structural directive:

```
<ng-template *myTemplate>
    <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

to this:

```
<ng-template myTemplate>
    <ng-template>
        <div>...</div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

This might be a problem in your case, if you are trying to render the outer template, as it will only contain a template inside, and thus nothing to render.